# EnableEvents not working

Tags: excel, vba

I'm new to VBA and am having an issue developing the code below. The code will hopefully run through about 500+ files and extract some data from various cells. Once I get this issue with the enableevents out the way.
At present, every xls file pops up with the “enable or disable macro” box. Any help will be great.

```
Sub ProcessAll(Optional sPath As Variant)
    Dim WB As Workbook, sFile As String

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    If IsMissing(sPath) Then
        sPath = "U:\Desktop\Temp\PEP Temp\"
        sFile = Dir(sPath & "*.xls")
    End If

     'Loop through all .xls-Files in that path
    Do While sFile <> ""
        Set WB = Workbooks.Open(sPath & sFile, , ReadOnly = True, , , , , , , , Notify = False)

        Debug.Print WB.Name

        WB.Close False
        sFile = Dir
    Loop
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

After doing some research i found that you can force excel to select disable macros with the following line of code

```
Application.AutomationSecurity = msoAutomationSecurityForceDisable
```

Comment: Sorry but I can't see how's the `Enable or Disable Macros` is related to the `EnableEvents`? I am not sure if that would change anything but try `Set WB = Workbooks.Open FileName:=sPath & sFile, ReadOnly:=True`

Comment: The securerity options in excel are quit strict by default. So you have to decrease this level. Excel declare VBA code as macro, because they are written in VBA

Answer (score 0):

From Excel Menu:
Files > Confidentiality center > Parameters > macros Parameters > choose wich one you need.

i tried to turn it into a vba macro using develeopper> record macro, but no success...

so i think you must do it manually.